# Accessing member function of std::shared_ptr in boost::graph?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, boost-graph, boost-property-map

I'm struggling transforming the usage of a `boost::graph` algorithm to a new set of implementation classes. I'm wondering: Is it even possible to access properties of an object, if the `boost::graph` only stores `std::shared_ptr` references? Like  in the following:

```
class Vert { 
public:
    Vert();
    Vert(std::string n);
    std::string getName() const;
    void setName( std::string const& n );
private:
    std::string name; 

};
typedef std::shared_ptr<Vert> Vert_ptr;

using namespace boost;
typedef boost::adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, directedS, Vert_ptr> Graph;
Graph g;
Vert_ptr a( new Vert("a"));
add_vertex( a, g );
std::ofstream dot("test.dot");
write_graphviz( dot, g, make_label_writer(boost::get(&Vert::getName,g))); //ERROR!
```

Is it possible to access members of a `std::shared_ptr` to use in the graph label writer `write_graphviz` or any other properties in the implementation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Yeah just use a transforming property map

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/34093a27a7450234)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>
#include <boost/property_map/transform_value_property_map.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <memory>

using namespace boost;

class Vert { 
public:
    Vert(std::string n="") : name(n) { }
    std::string getName() const { return name; }
    void setName( std::string const& n ) { name = n; }
private:
    std::string name; 
};

typedef std::shared_ptr<Vert> Vert_ptr;

struct Name { std::string operator()(Vert_ptr const& sp) const { return sp->getName(); } };

int main() {
    typedef boost::adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, directedS, Vert_ptr> Graph;
    Graph g;
    Vert_ptr a( new Vert("a"));
    add_vertex( a, g );
    std::ofstream dot("test.dot");
    auto name = boost::make_transform_value_property_map(Name{}, get(vertex_bundle,g));
    write_graphviz( dot, g, make_label_writer(name));
}
```

Result:

```
digraph G {
0[label=a];
}
```

Comment: Thank you... although my current boost version (v1.50) doesn't know `make_transform_value_property_map` I believe. After that I've to check if my compiler (MSVC2010) if it does support this `Name{}` syntax.

Comment: Transform-value property map introduced r77535 March 25th 2012, meaning it's in 1.56 at least. I have an alternative idea. Hang on